# Limit max. width for widescreen displays (Bootstrap)

Tags: max, column-width

Hi guys and first of all: I have zero coding knowledge. Sorry in advance!

What I'm currently trying to achieve is that my website (wordpress) keeps a max width of 1920. For example, when I have a picture in a full width row (stretch row and content, no paddings), it fits perfectly on a 1920x1080 monitor. But on a widescreen monitor like 21:9, it scales further to fit the whole width of the monitor. Is there any way to prevent the site or content from scaling wider than 1920px?

The developers of my theme are not a huge help. All they told me is that the theme is using Bootstrap Grid and Page Builder.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Hi Dennis, welcome to StackOverflow. Since your question is lacking implementation details of the wordpress theme, it will be hard for anyone to answer this question. If you pass this on to someone with a little coding knowledge, you can tell them to look into the [documentation of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) or use the `max-width` CSS property on one of the containers. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Melle. What further information should I provide to make the question more understandable?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to add styles to your HTML, you could use the following style on the body:

```
body: {
    max-width: 1920px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I assume you're not talking about adding that code to the additional css section of the page, right? Because that generates an error message.